# BlazeDS and Flash Builder, Inheritance generation problem

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash-builder, blazeds

I have a server with some simple java objects running. I want to build the client with Flex and connect to the server data with BlazeDS. The problem is the Flash Builder is not generating the Classes correctly. Just the properties are being generated, the inheritance are not being generates.

Is it a limitation or something is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK inheritance is not supported in Flash Builder / Fiber. We ran into the same problem on a current project and ended up writing a custom code generator ourselves. If time permits, I would suggest to do the same, as you'll have complete control over the generation process.